# Manter efeito final do Animation css

Tags: css, css3, css-animations

Estou fazendo uma tela de loading e no final do efeito, o valor de css que deve ser mantido, é o valor que está no 100% do animation, só que quando o efeito termina, ele volta ao css inicial.

Como faço para executar o efeito e manter o valor que está no 100%?

Css:

```
.loading_home_logo {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: -70px;
  animation: move-logo 4s;
}
@keyframes move-logo {
  0% {
    right: inherit;
    top: -10vh
  }
  50% {
    top: -40vh;
    left: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    top: -50vh;
    right: inherit;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc tem que usar o `animation-fill-mode` para parar a animação no final. No caso seria esse propriedade com o valor `forwards`, seria assim: `animation-fill-mode:forwards`

Consulte aqui as opções: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

Segue um exemplo sismples pra vc entender. Veja que no final o elemento não volta para o início, mas a animação só acontece uma vez... s*e vc quiser que ela se repita use a propriedade* `animation-iteration-count` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count

```css
.loading_home_logo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
  animation: move-logo 2s;
  /* animation-iteration-count: 3; */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes move-logo {
    0% {
        left: 0;
        background-color: red;
    }
    100% {
        left: 200px;
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading_home_logo">123</div>
```